# How to mock Entity Framework using IdentityDbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web app with individual authentication to store details about users cars. I will need to unit test the web app by mocking the entity framework, thus I have read I will need to implement an interface for the `ApplicationDbContext` class.

This is my first attempt at using entity framework and I just wanted to check whether my `ApplicationDbContext` class and interface will be suitable for mocking the framework when unit testing?

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    DbSet<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }
    int SaveChanges();
    void MarkAsModified(CarModel car);
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationDb", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }

    public override IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public void MarkAsModified(CarModel car)
    {
        Entry(car).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Some of the classes were formed by autocorrect using Visual Studios "Quick Actions". Could anyone explain why the `ApplicationUser` models require `IDbSet`, but the `CarModels` require just `DbSet`, and why the `Users` in the `ApplicationDbContext` class require an override?

Comment: Your DbContext properties should probably be public virtual if you are going to be mocking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anyone explain why the ApplicationUser models require IDbSet, but the CarModels require just DbSet

[IdentityDbContext class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext(v=vs.108).aspx) by design used `IDbSet<TEntity>` for both [Users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151757(v=vs.108).aspx) and [Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151756(v=vs.108).aspx) properties

```
public virtual IDbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
public virtual IDbSet<TRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

In your case you can follow the same pattern

```
public virtual IDbSet<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }
```

and update your interface to match as well

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext : IDisposable {
    IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    IDbSet<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }
    int SaveChanges();
    void MarkAsModified(CarModel car);
}
```

The interface can then be safely mocked for your isolated unit tests, provided the interface was being injected into the subject under test.

> and why the Users in the ApplicationDbContext class require an override?

It does not actually need to be overridden as the generic nature of the class (ie `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`) would already make the property follow the provided `ApplicationUser` type. You could have just as easily left it out.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext 
    : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext {

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationDb", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }

    public void MarkAsModified(CarModel car) {
        Entry(car).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```